# Order receipt e-mail language for guest checkout

Tags: 8, commerce, i18n-l10n

Is there a way to have the order receipt e-mail be in the language of the site version that was used for placing the order?

The order receipt e-mail that gets sent out (content of commerce-order-receipt.html.twig) for a guest is currently always in the default language. That means a user would order items from the French site, and get an English confirmation. It appears that no language data is saved for an order, so I guess there's no built-in way to do this.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem. Orders need a language field.

That will be added as a part of https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce/issues/2603482

Comment: I thought as much. Considering you opened that issue almost 3 years ago though, I think it might be another couple of years before there is real progress.

I suppose that for now I can add acustom  language field to orders and create a custom module with an updated copy of OrderReceiptSubscriber.php that reads said field. 
Or is there a better option available?

Comment: Sounds like a decent plan to me.